# Google spreadsheet copy column with =DATEVALUE()

Tags: google-sheets

I want to copy a column of Strighe and convert them to date.

I managed to do it with a single cell but I need to do it with the entire column .

For the single cell I used this :
=DATEVALUE( MID(A1;1;99))

but if I use that does not work :
=DATEVALUE( MID(A1:A999;1;99))

Comment: I managed to do it alone without having to convert the data strings : = { A19 : A999 } . But I want to simultaneously convert strings in data format! Help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula for whole column

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A="",IFERROR(1/0), DATEVALUE( MID(A1:A,1,99))))
```

[example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fU7rlo7Yuaxp2R_87YN44IM60fqyOfcWx7rqzQd4OUA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you so much you were very kind! But as ever to me I gave me error putting the commas? Instead I managed to make it work with ";" . Ie: = ARRAYFORMULA (IF (A19: A = ""; IFERROR (1/0); DATEVALUE (MID (A19: A; 1; 99))))